# LDAP and PAM working for GUI login but not SSH

Tags: debian, pam, ldap

I have two Debian VMs. one is running an LDAP server and I'm trying to get the other to use libpam_ldap.

The client machine is able to get users from LDAP for the GUI login screen, but I can't ssh into the VM with users that are only in LDAP. I also can't `su` from the root user (local) to an LDAP user, but I assume it's the same problem.

On the client machine, I can use `ldapsearch` to look up the user I want...

```
ldapsearch  -x -D "cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W -b "uid=testuser,ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
```

This prompts me for the admin LDAP password, and returns my user record:

```
dn: uid=testuser,ou=People,dc=mydomain,dc=com
uid: testuser
cn: Test User
objectClass: account
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: top
objectClass: shadowAccount
userPassword:: [removed for stackexchange posting ]
shadowLastChange: 17543
shadowMax: 99999
shadowWarning: 7
loginShell: /bin/bash
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 1001
homeDirectory: /home/dwill
gecos: Test User,,,
```

(note, my domain isn't *acutually* "mydomain.com".  I edited it for this posting)

But when I do `getent passwd testuser`, it doesn't return anything.

the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` has these lines

```
passwd:         files ldap
group:          files ldap
shadow:         files ldap
```

It used to have `compat ldap` for those but I tried changing it `files` because that's what one of the guides I found had.  It didn't work either way.

The `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has `UsePAM yes` set.

I have followed all the guides I can find via Google and I still can't get this working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `getent passwd` return the full user list? Are you using the `libpam-ldapd` package (recommended over `libpam-ldap`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.  One of the guides I found on Google instructed me to do

`apt-get libnss-ldap libpam-ldap nslcd`

I also later found an article that said that `libpam-ldapd` is newer than `libpam-ldap` and installed that instead.

`libnss-ldap` prompts you for some configuration and creates a `/etc/libnss-ldap.conf` file.  Then `libpam-ldap` uninstalls `libnss-ldap` but leaves its config file behind.  Apparently that config file is still meaningful because that's the one it's using and I had an error in the binddn in that file.  After fixing the binddn, it worked.

I really don't know why you'd install both of those ldap modules.  After getting the first client VM working, I setup another client VM using just libpam-ldapd and nslcd and it worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a `/etc/pam.d/sshd` with the following content:

```
auth    sufficient      pam_ldap.so
account sufficient      pam_permit.so
```

Then, run `sudo /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update` and you restart the `sshd` service.

Comment: It includes the common-auth and common-account files which both are configured to have those.  I tried putting them in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` also anyway but it didn't help.  Also, the LDAP users don't show up when you do `getent passwd` either.

Comment: Also, the LDAP users don't show up when you do `getent passwd` either. <---- this means your LDAP config is incorrect!